# $a+b\sqrt{5}$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ if its norm $N(a+b\sqrt{5})=a^2-5b^2$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

I'm struggling with the following problem.

Given the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]:=\{a+b\sqrt{5}\,/\,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, we define the norm $N:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]\to\mathbb{Z}\;/\;N(a+b\sqrt{5})=a^2-5b^2$. I have succesfully proven that $N$ is multiplicative, i.e., $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$; and that $x$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ if and only if $N(x)$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}$. Next, the problem asks me to prove the following statement:

> "If $N(x)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $x$ is prime in
> $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}].$"

This is proving to be quite the challenge. I understand that an element $x$ is prime if $x|mn\Rightarrow x|m \lor x|n$. So far, I've only been able to prove that if $N(x)$ is prime, $x$ is irreducible.

After some time, I began to think that maybe the source of the problem was mistaken and meant irreducible instead of prime, seeing as both definitions are equivalent in $\mathbb{Z}$. However, I haven't been able to find a suitable counterexample so far. So, my question is, is the claim true? If so, how could I prove it?

Comment: Can you use the fact that the ring of all algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is a PID?

Comment: @BarrySmith Is it so? How can it be proved, if I may ask?

Comment: Yes. One way is to prove that it is a Euclidean domain with respect to its norm. Google a .pdf of Hardy and Wright, for instance, and check out Section 14.8.

Comment: @BarrySmith Thanks, I didn't know that fact, but now I understand why that's the case! However, I still can't see how this property can be applied to prove the statement about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$

Comment: Since the only difference with going to the full ring is some factors of 2, I think you can probably use parity arguments after factoring things down in the full ring. I’d start I guess by showing that the norm of x is not 2.

Comment: @BarrySmith Sorry, but I don't understand. What do you mean by "the only difference with going to the full ring is some factors of 2"? Also, I see how factoring things in the full ring could help us prove that x is irreducible, and therefore prime, in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$, but how does that affect the primality in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$?

Comment: Algebraic integers in the full ring just have the form $a/2 + b/2 \sqrt{5}$ where $a$ and $b$ are rational integers with the same parity. So multiplying one of these by 2 always produces an integer in your ring. To then show that $x$ divides $m$ in your ring, then, show it divides $m$ in the slightly larger ring. Then write down a factorization $m = x k$, say, and show that in fact $k$ has to be in your ring. I think this may be done with parity arguments.

Comment: @BarrySmith Oooh thanks, I get it now! I'll try going down that route and see if I can do it.